# PL/SQL Error ORA-01722 when looping through cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, ora-01722

For a project I need to modify some attributes in a table based off of the value of that same attribute. I decided to go with cursors, and wrote the following:

```
DECLARE
totale_rente rekening.saldo%TYPE;
cursor c_boven1000 is
select r.reknummer,
       r.saldo,
       rt.rentepercentage,
       ABS(ROUND(r.saldo * (rt.rentepercentage/100), 2 )) as teBetalen
       FROM rekening r
       join rekeningtype rt on rt.naam = r.rekeningtype
       Where r.saldo < 0 and saldo >= -1000;
 cursor c_onder1000 is 
 select r.reknummer,
        r.saldo,
        rt.rentepercentage,
        ABS(ROUND(r.saldo * ((rt.rentepercentage*2)/100), 2 )) as teBetalen
        From rekening r
        join rekeningtype rt on rt.naam = r.rekeningtype
        Where r.saldo < -1000;

 TYPE rek_saldo IS TABLE OF rekening.saldo%TYPE;
 TYPE rek_nummer IS TABLE OF rekening.reknummer%TYPE;
 TYPE type_percentage IS TABLE OF rekeningtype.rentepercentage%TYPE;
 TYPE rek_tebetalen IS TABLE OF rekening.saldo%TYPE;

 rek_saldos rek_saldo;
 rek_nummers rek_nummer;
 type_percentages type_percentage;
 rek_tebetalens rek_tebetalen;

BEGIN
OPEN c_boven1000;
FETCH c_boven1000 BULK COLLECT INTO rek_saldos, rek_nummers, type_percentages, rek_tebetalens;
CLOSE c_boven1000;
FOR x IN rek_nummers.first..rek_nummers.last LOOP
    UPDATE rekening r
    SET r.saldo = r.saldo - rek_tebetalens(x)
    WHERE r.reknummer = rek_nummers(x);
    totale_rente := totale_rente + rek_tebetalens(x);
END LOOP;
OPEN c_onder1000;
FETCH c_onder1000 BULK COLLECT INTO rek_saldos, rek_nummers, type_percentages, rek_tebetalens;
CLOSE c_onder1000;
FOR x IN rek_nummers.first..rek_nummers.last LOOP
    UPDATE rekening r
    SET r.saldo = r.saldo - rek_tebetalens(x)
    WHERE r.reknummer = rek_nummers(x);
    totale_rente := totale_rente + rek_tebetalens(x);
END LOOP;    

    UPDATE rekening r
    SET saldo = saldo + totale_rente
    WHERE r.reknummer = '2250';
END;
```

In this case, `reknummer` is a Varchar, `saldo` is a number(10,2), `rentepercentage` is a number (3,2).

When executing, i got the following error:

> ORA-01722: Invalid number for execute PL/SQL code.

Not sure if it is important, but this code block is inside a dynamic action on clicking a button.
I have tried to find my error, but have been unable to.
Could anyone assist?

Comment: Is this a full error message?

Comment: The very first suggestion I have is to reconsider your algorithm. You are opening the cursor twice to retrieve just a single record. This can be done without a cursor (cursors are aimed to retrieve a dataset/collection of records and then loop through them one by one). Once you have changed your code and eliminate all errors (including 01722), update your question with more info.

Comment: I'm using two different cursors based of the value of the attribute rekening.saldo, because if saldo < -1000, the new value of rekening.saldo needs to be calculated using double the value of rekeningtype.rentepercentage. I do not know of a different way of doing this. Do you have any advice on how to do it differently?

Comment: The column order in `c_boven1000`and `c_onder1000` don't match the collection order in the `bulk collect into`clauses; you've swapped `saldo` and `reknummer`? This seems overly complicated though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order in which you select your columns and the order of the variables is not the same.

```
 select r.reknummer
       ,r.saldo
       ,rt.rentepercentage

 into rek_saldos
          ,rek_nummers
          ,type_percentages
```

You can use a case statement in your cursor as such:

```
select r.reknummer
      ,r.saldo
      ,rt.rentepercentage
      ,case
          when saldo >= -1000 then
           abs(round(r.saldo * (rt.rentepercentage / 100), 2))
          else
           abs(round(r.saldo * ((rt.rentepercentage * 2) / 100), 2))
       end as tebetalen
  from rekening r
  join rekeningtype rt
    on rt.naam = r.rekeningtype
 where r.saldo < 0
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up, it's always the little things that are the hardest to spot for me. It's working perfectly as intended now.